# How to sort a list of files & directories so directories are listed first in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort a list of files & directories so directories are listed first in PHP???
I try natsort but it only sort alphabeticaly.
My source:

```
$dirFiles = array();
$path = "./folder_path";
// opens images folder
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." &&  $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != "Thumbnails" && $file != ".DS_Store") {
        $isdir = $path . $file;
         if(is_dir($isdir)){
            $dirFiles[] = $file;
         }
         if(!is_dir($isdir)){
            $dirFiles[] = $file;
         }
        }
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
natsort($dirFiles);
```

Listing files and directories

```
foreach($dirFiles as $file => $value)
{
     $name = basename($value);
     echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a multidimensional array:

```
if(is_dir($isdir)){
    $dirFiles['dir'][] = $file;
}
if(!is_dir($isdir)){
    $dirFiles['file'][] = $file;
}
```

To list files and directories:

```
ksort($dirFiles);
foreach($dirFiles as $files)
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $name = basename($file);
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a sort function with a default callback:

```
uasort($dirFiles, "folderFirstSort");

function folderFirstSort($a, $b){
   if (is_dir($a) && !is_dir($b)){
      //a is dir, should be "smaller"
      return -1;
   }else if (!is_dir($a) && is_dir($b)){
      //b is dir, should be "smaller"
      return 1;
   }else{
      //both are files OR folders, compare names
      return strcmp($a,$b);
   }
}
```

Maybe you need to swap the returns of `-1` and `1` - i always confuse them and play arround until it matches the desired outcome :)